# eXTjS 3.3.1 LiveGrid store.each gives only buffered rows

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I use ExtJs 3.3.1 because many extensions don't work under 4.xx
One of these extensions is LiveGrid.
I can't try but i suppose a simmilar thing happens with a 4.x buffered grid.
When i do a report of the lines visible in the grid only the buffered lines are returned, i reposition the current record but the loading of the rest of the records only happens after the reporting finishes. How can i get all the records ?

In an button handler i call toReport(grid).

```
  toReport = function(grid){
    var store = grid.getStore();
    var view = grid.getView();
    store.each(function(record) {
      Ext.defer(function(){
        index = readRow(store, record);
        if (index % 10 == 0){
          view.focusRow(index);
        }
      }, 500, this);
    });
    console.log(output)
  }

readRow = function(store, record){
  output = "";
  for (var xlCol=1;xlCol<record.fields.length+1;xlCol++){
    var veld = store.fields.itemAt(xlCol-1).name;
    waarde = record.get(veld);
    if (realTypeOf(waarde)==="date"){
      output += waarde.format("d-m-Y");
    }else{
      output += record.get(veld);
    }
  }
  console.log(store.indexOf(record)+ " " + output);
  return store.indexOf(record);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a solution by using recursion.
Like this the view kan keep up with the enumeration.

```
  Ext.toExcel = function(grid){
    var store = grid.getStore();
    var view = grid.getView();
    readRow(store, view, 0);
  }

  readRow = function(store, view, index){
    output = "";
    record = store.getAt(index);
    for (var xlCol=1;xlCol<record.fields.length+1;xlCol++){
      var veld = store.fields.itemAt(xlCol-1).name;
      waarde = record.get(veld);
      if (realTypeOf(waarde)==="date"){
        output += waarde.format("d-m-Y");
      }else{
        output += record.get(veld);
      }
    }
    //console.log(index+ " " + output);
    if (index % 50 == 0){view.focusRow(index);}

    Ext.defer(function(){
      if (index < store.totalLength){
        readRow(store, view, index+1);
      }
    }, 100, this);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The grid needs to manipulate its store filters, sorters, paging, etc., in order to obtain the records it want to display. The store itself only keeps in memory the subset of records that matches its filters, etc. That is the way stores are designed in Ext: they are intended to be bounded to one and only one view.

I think in your case, the simplest solution is to create another store with a similar configuration, and use its `load` method with params such that you get all the records.

If you're reticent to fire multiple requests for retrieving essentially the same data, have a look at `Ext.data.Proxy`. Unlike stores, proxies are not bound to a specific view or task and can be shared between multiple store instances. So in theory, you can create a proxy that requests all the records from the server at once, and then feeds a subset of them to multiple stores. For that you'll have to implement the [`doRequest`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.DataProxy-cfg-doRequest) method of the proxy (or most probably overrides the one of the proxy you're already using).